# Equivalent of @JsonIgnore for a request in Spring MVC

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have a collection which has a `DBRef` inside it (and this  secondary collection has a not `null` field).  When I am using `@ResponseBody`, I am getting a `415` HTTP response. If I remove this secondary collection then everything works properly.

Is there way I can say certain fields are for input and certain field are for output in Spring MVC?

I see `@JsonIgnore` only for outgoing response. But did not find anything for input.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please provide your controller method ?Your example code probably ?

Comment: If @RequestBody is not required you can mark it as nullable. @RequestBody(required = false). In this case your controller will ignore it if its not present,

Answer (score 1):

> Is there way I can say certain fields are for input and certain field are for output in Spring MVC?

Solution to the problem is to ensure Setter is ignored and getter is not.

```
@Getter
@Setter(onMethod = @__( @JsonIgnore ))
private String FullName;
```

In the above example FullName is calculated by FirstName and LastName and should not be set using json input

```
{
  "FirstName":"VinayaKumar"
  "LastName":"Thimmappa"
}
```